# How to inject or customize Angular validation behaviour

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

AngularJS supports some validation directives for an input as: 'required', 'min', ...
When the input fails on validation rule, example 'required', input will have a class name 'ng-invalid-required' which showing a red border.

Ex:

```
<input id="username" name="username" type="text" ng-model="userName" required data-hint="Please input your username" />
```

I want to change this default behaviour to show a tooltip or a hint "Please input your username" when input is empty.

Is there a solution to inject a Angular method or have to write a custom directive? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the default behavior of Angular about validation is not to create a tooltip under the field? Or maybe you only want to change the default text?

Anyway, you can custom it following this example : http://dailyjs.com/2013/06/06/angularjs-7/

Don't forget the "novalidate" on the form markup (because of HTML5) and if you don't want the button to be disabled, you will need to check for the validity of the form before executing the function :

```
$scope.mySubmitFunction = function() {
    if (! $scope.myForm.$invalid) {
        ...
    }
};
```

Hope this helps